# Red black tree deletion unknown behaviour

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, red-black-tree, tree-balancing

I entered several numbers to a red black tree. (41; 38; 31;
12; 19; 8) after deleting 8 and 12 (1st screenshot) it got into the type of the second screenshot. I can't understand why that 31 turn into red . Please help  me with that ? If you could please mention the case related to that.
Thank you !

[image]

Comment: Do you understand the definition of a red-black tree? If the `0031` node had remained black, would the tree still satisfy the constraints? (Answer: no.) Why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the explanation of the removal algorithm on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree#Removal), you can map their naming of nodes to your tree as follows:

**M** = 0012, the black node to remove
**C** = a NIL leaf below 0012 (NILs are always considered to be black)

The article goes on to say about your actual case:

> The complex case is when both **M** and **C** are black. [...] We begin by replacing **M** with its child **C**. [...] We will *relabel* this child **C** (in its new position) **N**, and its sibling (its new parent's other child) **S** [...] we will also use **P** for **N**'s new parent, **S<sub>L</sub>** for **S**'s left child, and **S<sub>R</sub>** for **S**'s right child

So now we have after the removal, but before re-colouring:

[image]

**P** = 0019 (red)
**N** = a NIL leaf, the left child of 0019
**S** = 0031, the right child of 0019

The description identifies several cases, and the case at hand is the following one:

> **Case 4: S** and **S**'s children are black, but **P** is red. In this case, we simply exchange the colors of **S** and **P**.

The reason for this colour swap is explained:

> This does not affect the number of black nodes on paths going through **S**, but it does add one to the number of black nodes on paths going through **N**, making up for the deleted black node on those paths.

Recall that in Red Black trees this invariant must be maintained ([property 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree#Properties)):

> Every path from a given node to any of its descendant NIL nodes contains the same number of black nodes.

This invariant would have been violated if the above colour-swap were omitted.